# Change File Icon to "Blank" Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, icons

I recently opened a `tar.gz` on my Windows 8.1 computer using WinRAR, so now it had the WinRAR icon. However, when I uninstalled WinRAR, the icon is still there. I tried refreshing the File Explorer windows to see if it was a temporary problem, however, no luck.

How do you change the icon back to the "blank" default icon for files that Windows doesn't have a program to open it with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

1. Reinstall WinRAR.
2. Uninstall using Revo Uninstaller or Geek Uninstaller.

If you uninstalled WinRAR through the default uninstaller it may left some configuration behind. This should fix.

Or you can install another program that does the same thing as WinRAR. I know that it isn't exactly what you want but it wouldn't leave a icon of a program that doesn't exists anymore around. I recommend Peazip.